# Compare argument in priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I would like to define a custom `priority_queue` as `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, TCOMP>`, where `int` here stores the index of a vector `arr` defined outside of `priority_queue`. Something like:

```
vector<int> arr = {2, 5, 1, 6, 10, 3};
struct TCOMP
{
    bool operator()(int index1, int index2) const
    { return arr[index1] < arr[index2]; }
}
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, TCOMP> pq;
```

Is there a way to do that? Note that I don't like to involve `int*` in this problem.

Comment: "Is there a way to do that?" - The syntax errors aside, didn't you just do it?

Comment: Better post an [mcve], if you're running into a specific problem. Otherwise clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, of course I tested it, and know that there are syntax errors. What I want is, how can I make a priority_queue contain only indices of a vector, so that the indices are heap-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the comparison predicate to the array explicitly. This will give you more flexibility, since you will be able to use it with different arrays.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct TCOMP
{
    const vector<int>& arr;
    TCOMP(const vector<int>* a) : arr(*a) {}

    bool operator()(int index1, int index2) const
    { return arr[index1] < arr[index2]; }
};


int main()
{
    vector<int> arr = {2, 5, 1, 6, 10, 3};
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, TCOMP> pq((TCOMP(&arr)));

    return 0;
}
```